# What is the difference between the WITH statement compared to CREATE TEMP TABLE in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

What is the difference between `WITH` statements and `CREATE TEMP TABLE` statements?

Both of them create what is a non-persistent table.

Does one have better performance then the other or is the difference purely stylistic?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13112/whats-the-difference-between-a-cte-and-a-temp-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between them is that tables created in a WITH statement only exist for that statement, whereas TEMP tables exist for the whole session.